# Can't login into shell

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I was trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04lts to 16.04 and one of the steps was "upgrade" command it took longer than it should have, but unfortunately while upgrading notebook's power run out and laptop has closed instantly.
Then I plugged the charger and opened the notebook again but I was unable to login, I was in login loop problem apparently somebody had that kind of problem before and answer says "ctrl + alt + f3" but I cant login, I'm typing my username first then the password that I use to login desktop. But it keep saying "incorrect login" .
Dunno what to do.

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the username? (it may be different from the 'full name' that's usually displayed in the GUI - especially things like capitalization)

Comment: I'm using my session's name go login.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm no expert. But this should work.

1. Boot into recovery mode. To do that, hold right shift in the screen after your BIOS. It should pull up GRUB2 menu, and navigate to "Ubuntu 16.04 (recovery mode)". Select it.
2. Select the "root" option.
3. Add a new user. Type "useradd username".
4. Give them a password. Type "passwd username password".
5. Make them an administrator. Type "usermod -a -G sudo username". If "sudo" isnt found, use "admin"
6. Type "reboot" to restart the computer. Log in with the user you used, and update Ubuntu with your charger plugged in.

Tell me if this doesn't work. I will put some research into it if it fails.

Comment: Using https://askubuntu.com/a/1206622/1718249 and these instructions, I was able to recover my WSL Ubuntu install that got messed up

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue as yours right now and i was shocked to not find a single solution. But what did work for me is not using the 'NUMPAD' to enter my password. I logged in instantly by using the numbers above the keyboard. Hope this works for you. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live usb disk, backup your home folder, do a clean install. It'll be a lot easier than trying to diagnose the mess of an incomplete upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I got tons of personal file in notebook (around 300gb) better trying to figure out what is going on.