# Unable to change the root password in Windows 10 WSL

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried both commands

```
sudo passwd
```

and

```
sudo -u root /bin/bash
```

But as soon as I enter the new password twice, it says password has been updated. You close the shell and open a new instance, it is still working on the old root password.

Please help.

Comment: well sudo -u root can be a desperate attempt to get things working. but sudo passwd should change the password. and old one should not be required when i open a new WSL shell and try 'sudo apt-get install'

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. in wsl, `sudo passwd` will change the password of the WSL root user.
2. in wsl, `passwd` will change the password of the current WSL user

- to specify which WSL user to use (temporarily) `wsl -u [user]`

3. in wsl, `passwd [user]` will change the password of any WSL user
4. in wsl, `sudo` generally asks for the password of the current WSL user.
5. in windows cmd.exe, you can change the default WSL user (permanently):

- in current versions: `ubuntu.exe config --default-user [user]`
- in legacy versions `1703`, `1709`: `lxrun /setdefaultuser [user]`
- a restart may be required

You probably want to change the password of the `sudo`-capable, non-root user.

You probably do not want to change the root users password (because in Ubuntu, the root user generally should not have a password, `sudo` should be used instead).
You probably also do not want to leave your default user as root. Even when working form windows, its still a bad practice.

Official Microsoft documentation on *User Accounts and Permissions* can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/user_support

Comment: I had to close Ubuntu and restart it for `ubuntu config --default-user [user]` to work.

Comment: Just a quick comment, as mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/966537/340341 , you need to follow the `ubuntu config` line with `sc stop LxssManager` and `sc stop LxssManager` for the update to work in the current shell

Comment: Relevant section of your link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support?redirectedfrom=MSDN#forgot-your-password
Microsoft uses the root user as example. Do they share bad practices? Why is it bad practice to give root a password?

Answer (score 254):

There is a simpler method.

1. Open cmd.exe
2. Type `wsl -u root`
3. Type `passwd username` and change the password
4. Type `exit`
5. Type `wsl`
6. Type `sudo echo hi` to confirm the new password works.

Comment: The method is simpler and the answer more clear and straightforward, worked perfectly

Comment: Also good for fixing anything preventing `sudo` from working

Comment: This works for me. I am using WSL Legacy(Default).

Comment: One liner version that combines steps 2-4 -- `wsl -u root passwd username`

Comment: I don know why, but this command seems not working for me, yes while I enter `wsl -u root` it simply accesses ubuntu root user, then I enter `passwd root` it asks for a new password, I enter the new password, and confirm by retyping, after that while I start ubuntu terminal and use `sudo su` the new password not work ...

Comment: @M.KHossain, is it possible that after you entered wsl with `wsl -u root` you then ran `passwd root` instead of `passwd ubuntu`?

Comment: Oh how many times I have came back for this!  Too many.

Comment: @M.KHossain You're resetting the password of the user that is doing the sudo. So in the normal console run `whoami` to determine your regular user. Then login as root to change the password for that user.

Comment: If you have mutliple distributions, you can also it using argument `-d`. e.g. 
`wsl -u root  -d Ubuntu-22.04`

Answer (score 29):

It is assumed you are using Ubuntu in this explanation.

- If you forgot your password on WSL simply open your command prompt from windows by typing cmd on search.
- Then type `ubuntu config --default-user root` to set root as the default user for Linux Bash Shell.
- Then open the Linux Bash shell which will log you in as root without asking for password.
- Then use `passwd username` to reset the password of any user.
- Use `ubuntu config --default-user username` to reset back to your normal Linux user account.

Comment: /bin/bash/: config: command not found

Comment: @systemovich - you need to run the `ubuntu config ...` commands from a windows command prompt (cmd.exe).  To open the bash shell from there, just type `wsl` and hit Enter. To return to the windows command prompt, from the WSL prompt, type `exit` and hit enter

Comment: There is a simpler method.

1. Open cmd.exe  
2. Type `wsl -u root`  
3. Type `passwd username` and change the password  
4. Type `exit`  
5. Type `wsl`  
6. Type `sudo echo h`' to confirm the new password works.

Comment: @bicole you can probably remove this comment as your provider answer is already up ahead of this answer :) and thanks! 

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to reconfigure Ubuntu, but, if you have more than one distribution installed and Ubuntu is not your default, you must also specify the distribution in addition to the root user.

- Option 1 -- Ubuntu is the default WSL distribution:

  ```
  wsl.exe -u root
  ```
- Option 2 -- Ubuntu is not the default WSL distribution:

  1. First determine the distribution name:

     ```
     wsl.exe -l -v
     ```
  2. Then use the distribution name with `-d`/`--distribution`:

     ```
     wsl.exe -d <distro> -u root
     ```

Then go about your business to reset your regular user account.  Stealing the one-liner from @NotTheDr01ds, assuming your distribution name is "Ubuntu":

```
wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -u root passwd username
```

Typical Ubuntu distribution names include:

- *Ubuntu*:  When installed from the Microsoft Store or `wsl --install` as the "unversioned" app.
- *Ubuntu-18.04*, *Ubuntu-20.04*, or *Ubuntu-22.04*:  When installed from the Microsoft Store or `wsl --install` as a specific version of Ubuntu.

Comment: wsl -d Ubuntu -u root passwd <user> didnt work for me :(

Comment: @user1599324 I've just edited the question with some details that will hopefully let it work for you.